Why do I have to sudo for libcamera-still? (Bookworm - PI5)
I am using a raspberry Pi5 with Debian Bookworm 24-3-15.
I ran a full upgrade on the system.
I installed a camera and got it to work (dtoverlay=imx219). If I am using the camera with libcamera-hello, it works like a charm (OK, I lied, but it works with --qt-preview since I was doing RDP - took me half a day to find this).
Anyway, I am using a custom user. I already added him to the video group.
So now my real issue:
This works:
sudo libcamera-still -o test.jpg

This fails:
libcamera-still -o test.jpg

Both are created in my home folder. I can create files there.
How can I figure out what permissions I am missing to create the image?
Which groups could I add my user to that could be messing up the command?
I am a windows guy mostly, and this is the 1st time "fighting" with *Nix system since decades (Damn I am getting old) ;)

How does it fail? Any error messages? What are they? Please [edit] your question and explain the failure.

You said you added the user to the video group, but did you logout and login again afterwards? A user that is already logged in cannot receive new group memberships in real time: to enjoy the perks of group membership, the user must be a member of the group at login time.
